# A binge is on its own

Tags: meaning, slang, semantics, sentence-meaning

I am quite sure that the sentence

> There was a **binge** yesterday

is grammatically correct. But what about semantics? I mean, there was an event like a drinking party yesterday. Do I use the **binge** word properly?
I want to use the **binge** word as a noun on its own. Is it allowed in this case?

I got some third-party opinion:

> It is not right to use the **binge** word in that way. Because *binge* on its own doesn't truly explain itself, you'd have to out 'drinking' there before or after it.
> E.g. 'There was a drinking binge yesterday'
> Or 'We went out binge drinking last night'

But this opinion is pretty dubious for me especially in the *drinking binge* part.

Is this sentence (*There was a binge yesterday*) really clumsy, inadequate and inappropriate in English speech?

In the novel *Decline and Fall* by Evelyn Waugh, I found a similar use of the word "binge":

> - How about a binge?
> - What about that binge you promised me and Prendy?
> - Here's to Trumpington, whoever he is, who gave us the money for this binge!

Comment: What do you intend for the sentence to mean? "Binge" doesn't always refer to alcohol

Comment: I'd be happier with 'Weekend binges are a serious problem at many colleges and universities' [[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/binge)] and 'Binge drinking is a serious problem at many colleges and universities' than 'Binges are a serious problem,' which while not incorrect feels in need of additional information (which may of course have been given in previous sentences). Compare 'There was a spree.'

Comment: Quiet sure? That's a new one. Would that everyone were quiet sure. "They *went on a binge* yesterday. "there was a binge" as used in  your sentence is awkward.

Comment: I feel sure that Bertie Wooster often used *binge* to mean (sometimes ironically) a festive occasion, **not** implying drunkenness (but not excluding it either).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the sentence *There was a binge yesterday* is both grammatically correct and clumsy and I'd venture so far as to say that few native speakers (certainly BrE speakers) would put things that way.

OED gives the definition of the noun *binge* as

> *slang* (originally *dialect*: see *Eng. Dial. Dict.*).
> A heavy drinking-bout; hence, a spree.

and it defines the verb *binge* as you'd expect, to indulge in such an event.

so while @alphabet's comment that *binge* doesn't *always* refer to an alcohol-soaked spree it usually does, and without qualification (as in eg *a coke and methamphetamine binge*) one would usually interpret it to be so, alcohol-soaked that is.

It would be more natural to say something like *I was on a binge last night* or *My flatmates went out on a binge for the weekend, I stayed in and studied the scriptures.*

The expression *There was a binge last night* is the kind of thing a university student might say to his mother (other sexes of student are available, as are other parents) when she visits one morning to find the shared accommodation in total disarray and when the student wishes to leave open the slim possibility that mother's darling son was not at the very heart of goings-on.

Comment: I suspect this may be a split between BrE and AmE; "I was on a binge last night" and "My [roommates] went out on a binge for the weekend" sound wrong to me without further context.

Comment: @alphabet No, the BrE and AmE here is exactly the same thing. My roommates went on a binge this weekend.

Comment: @Lambie I can confidently say that I have never heard this usage, except where context makes the activity in question clear.

Comment: @alphabet This is very used, in several variants: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/binge to go or be on a binge and the verb: to binge.

Comment: @Lambie In their use of "on a binge," they specify the activity in question (eating) and their definition there makes no reference to alcohol.

Comment: @Lambie Likewise, with "binge" as a verb, they specify what is being consumed ("chocolate" or "ice cream") and again their definition of that verb makes no specific reference to drinking or alcohol.

Comment: You may have heard a usage that I haven't; some other dictionaries do include a meaning that refers primarily or exclusively to alcohol. Cambridge doesn't, though, and that's consistent with how I've heard the word used.

Comment: @alphabet It is not that I have "heard of usage". I just know how the word is used. I never said anything about alcohol, did I? You can go on a binge, or you can binge. There are all kinds of binges, including watching a TV series in full. However, "there was a binge yesterday" is not right. "They were on a binge yesterday", would be. drinking binge, chocolate binge, ice cream binge, pizza binge, whatever.

Comment: @Lambie Obviously you would say that you were on a binge, not that the binge existed. My point is that "I was on a binge last night" *on its own* would also be incorrect or at least oddly ambiguous.

Comment: (That's the real question OP was asking--it was about the need to add "drinking" to the sentence.)

Comment: (Anyway, probably unwise to keep arguing in the comments. Feel free to downvote my answer and/or post your own.)

Comment: Not "I was on a binge" but "I *went* on a binge".

Comment: @WeatherVane That is not accurate: If I’m going to be on a binge, I’m going to be way above 350. So, I feel like I’m pretty safe at a 20 [unit] dose. [insulin taker] A real speaker. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9554983/

Comment: @high About few native speakers. I have found the novel Decline and Fall by Evelyn Waugh and he also uses "binge" in that way. E.g. 
_How about a binge?_ 
_What about that binge you promised me and Prendy?_ 
_Here's to Trumpington, whoever he is, who gave us the money for this binge!_

Comment: @alphabet In the UK "**to go on a binge**" does hint of drinking heavily. **Binge eating** (timeline: I'm guessing ) was a product of the late 70s and 80s. **Binge drinking** was a thing in the 90s and noughts. Then that drifted to **binge watching** and **binging on___**

Answer (score 2):

I certainly haven't heard this usage of "binge" before. Typically you need to specify what activity was being done, since "binge" can refer to bingeing on a variety of things: drinking, eating, shopping, watching shows on Netflix, *et cetera.* So you would say "a drinking binge" to refer to one episode of overconsuming alcohol or "binge drinking" to refer to the activity of doing so. (Incidentally, "a bender" sounds much better to me than "a drinking binge.")

[Cambridge gives this definition:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/binge)

> an occasion when an activity is done in an extreme way, especially eating, drinking, or spending money:
>
> - *a drinking/eating/spending binge*
> - *He went on a five day drinking binge*

That said, you could omit "drinking" if it was extremely obvious from the surrounding context:

> After being sober for ten years, Jim relapsed, going on a three-day binge.